# static progressbar with jquery

Tags: jquery

i'am a newbie with jquery and i need some example with a static progressbar with jquery that i will use it for displaying some statistics , for exemple 90% of students have made it to the second grade, so i need some progressbar with static number (90%)

i found some stufs like that but its not helping

var bar = $('span');
                var p = $('p');

```
            var width = bar.attr('style');
            width = width.replace("width:", "");
            width = width.substr(0, width.length-1);


            var interval;
            var start = 0; 
            var end = parseInt(width);
            var current = start;

            var countUp = function() {
              current++;
              p.html(current + "%");


              if (current === end) {
                clearInterval(interval);
              }
            };

            interval = setInterval(countUp, (1000 / (end + 1)));
```

[image]

any help or tutorial please.

Comment: I can't see the question in this long post.

Comment: look at the image there , i just need some jquery code to have something like that , but not a progessbar that will begin from 0 to 100% but something with a static value that can be changed to get a particular value .

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me as though you're referring to a chart not a progress bar.

I really enjoy chartjs.org

There are plenty of options. One I've recently discovered is Piety
https://github.com/benpickles/peity

There's also the ever popular (though probably way beyond what you're wanting) D3: http://d3js.org/

**[Update]**
I put together this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/27po97a7/ you could use javascript to set the width of `.progress` and the text.

Comment: somehow you are right , but i need the style of a progressbar

Comment: "a progressbar" is not a style. Maybe do a mockup of what you're looking for.

Comment: i just add an image in the question